# pThreads Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, pthreads, malloc

This is the struct passed to thread declaration:

```
   typedef struct  {
              int rowsPerThread;                    
              int StartingRow;                     
              double co[WIDTH][HEIGHT][2];          
              uint64_t total_iters;                

      } thdata;
```

And here's how I use it: (notice the malloc)

```
  /* data passed to each thread */
  thdata *data[threads_num];


  /* create threads */
  for (i=0; i<threads_num; i++)
  {
      data[i]=(thdata *)malloc(sizeof(thdata));
      data[i]->rowsPerThread= rowsPerThread;
      data[i]->StartingRow= i*rowsPerThread;

      for (i=i*rowsPerThread; i<rowsPerThread; i++)
      memcpy(data[i]->co[i], Coordinates[i], sizeof (Coordinates) * HEIGHT * 2);


      pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, (void *) &threaded_calc, (void *) &data[i]);   
      free(data[i]);
  }
```

I think there's a problem with the malloc().

It gives me segmentation fault.

Comment: Is your `threaded_calc` thread using the &data[i] that you pass in ?(you probably want to pass in `data[i]` too instead of `&data[i]`)  If it does, it seems unwise to do `free(data[i])` here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you `free` your `data[i]` in the `for` block, right after creation of a `pthread` and since you cannot know when the `thread` is started, it may be possible that `data[i]` is *freed* before the `thread` is effectively started by the `scheduler`.

So, you should call `free` inside the thread body.

Comment: This + passing just data[i] instead of &data[i] as @nos suggested did the trick.

Thanks both of you.